# Rearranging an array such that positive and negative elements are at alternate positions while maintntaining relative order

Tags: java, arrays

We are given an array in which we have equal number of positive and negative elements. We have to rearrange this array such that all positive and negative elements are at alternate positions and also, **respective order** should be maintained. N i.e. the size of array can be: 1<=N<=10^6 .  **Without using additional data structures**
INPUT:
1 2 3 -1 -2 -3
1 -4 -7 6 -5 2
OUTPUT:
1 -1 2 -2 3 -3
1 -4 6 -7 2 -5
My code was accepted but it exceeded the time limit for a case. How can I make my code more efficient by reducing its time complexity?
My code:

```
import java.util.*;
 class A{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
     int n=s.nextInt();
     int a[]=new int[n];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         a[i]=s.nextInt();
     rearrange(a);
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
 }

public static void rotateright(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    int temp=a[r];
    for(int i=r;i>l;i--)
    {
        a[i]=a[i-1];
    }
    a[l]=temp;
}
public static void rearrange(int a[])
{
    int n=a.length;
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(i<n)
    {   
        if(i%2==0)    //even index should have positive element
        {
            if(a[i]>0)     //already positive
                i++;
            else               //for negative
            {
                j=i+1;
                while(j<n)      //finding next positive
                {
                    if(a[j]>0)
                        break;
                    j++;
                }
                rotateright(a,i,j);    //making even index positive
                i++;
            }
        }
        else            //odd index should have negative element
        {
            if(a[i]<0)   //already negative
                i++;
            else           //for positive
            {
                j=i+1;
                while(j<n)          //finding next negative
                {
                    if(a[j]<0)
                        break;
                    j++;
                }
                rotateright(a,i,j);     //making odd index negative
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seems like sorting with absolute value unless I am missing something here.

Comment: I updated the example.

Comment: `even index should have positive element` -- but what if they start the input with a negative number? Since they should alternate won't even positions now have negative numbers? Or have they said explicitly that input will start with positive number only?

Comment: even indices(0,2,4..) will have negative elements if it starts it with a negative element the first index i.e. 0 is already arranged that's why I am using the continue statement in first case. Also it is not mandatory to have negative at even indices we can have positives their too. But I am taking it as a frame to work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trivial to do this in O(n) so long as you aren't required to shuffle the array in-place (NB: that requirement was *not* explicitly stated when the question was first posted) :

```
static public int[] reorder(int[] input) {
    int[] output = new int[input.length];
    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 1;
    for (int val: input) {
        if (val >= 0) {   // treat zero as positive
            output[pos] = val;
            pos += 2;
        } else {
            output[neg] = val;
            neg += 2;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Does use double memory for result array, while question is asking for in-place rearrange. Don't know if that's a hard restriction, so you got my up-vote. You can always copy values back if original must be updated, but it still uses double memory during rearrange.

Comment: @Andreas it says "rearrange", it doesn't (explicitly) say in place.

Comment: You can drop the `if (val < 0)`. The `else` is enough. You could change first `if` to `val >= 0`, in case they consider zero to be a positive number, so all values are arranged.

Comment: @Andreas I put that there to make it more explicit that I'm not handling the == 0 case.  Alternatively, yes, we could treat zero as "positive".

Comment: it is inplace. No additional array can be used.

Comment: @sahilmehta you should have said so explicitly in the question!

Comment: I thought rearrange meant the same. Anyway, I updated it already :)

Answer (score -1):

You could go through the array and get all the positive elements and put them in a separate array like this:

```js
B=[a.length]
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
if(a[i]>0){
b.add(a[i])
}
}
for(int x=0;x<b.length;x++){
for(int b=0;b<a.length;b++){
if(a[b]*-1==b[x]){
b[x+1]=a[]
}
}
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting it wrong.  INPUT: 1 2 -4 -7 -5 3   OUTPUT: 1 -4 2 -7 3 -5

Comment: In second example in code, `a[b]*-1==b[x]` will never be true.

Answer (score -1):

You can get an nlog(n) solution if you sort the array then walk with 2 indexes. One starting on the negative numbers at index 0, the other starting at the positive numbers at index n/2. Then just increment both indices walking the array and copying them into a new array. You could also probably do something where you keep everything in the same array to save memory/allocation costs. I don't think a downvote is warranted here. (This is assuming only the first example input, output pair as originally asked.) Included code(it's in C#) to show that it works including test.

```
[TestCase(new int[] { 5, -3, 4, -1 }, new int[] { -3, 4, -1, 5 })]
public void Test1(int[] before, int[] after)
{
    var arrangedList = Arrange(before.ToList());
    Assert.AreEqual(after, arrangedList.ToArray());
}

public static List<int> Arrange(List<int> numbers)
{
    numbers.Sort();

    int gapSize = numbers.Count / 2;
    return Enumerable.Range(0, gapSize)
        .SelectMany(negativeIndex => new int[] { negativeIndex, negativeIndex + gapSize })
        .Select(index => numbers[index])
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Values must maintain original order, i.e. positive numbers must maintain relative order, and should not the sorted. See second example that's been added to question.

Comment: @Andreas Respective order is fairly ambiguous, my initial thought was that respective order implied that all positive values should be ordered and all negative values should be ordered which would invalidate the accepted solution. The key being that they should also alternate which if it holds would have invalidated the accepted solution.

Comment: @Nathan AIUI, it means that each positive value should maintain its respective position to the _other positive values_, and likewise for the negative ones, but not with the other set.

Comment: @Alnitak included quick solution and run test case to verify correctness.

Comment: @Nathan That is not Java code, it sorts the values, which updated question shows is not valid, and it uses extra data structure, which later update to question says is not allowed.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't include code originally since I default to C#, that is why I just included the algorithm description. I included this to show that the algorithm does keep the outputs in the correct order. As far as the question prohibiting sorting, I don't see that, I see prohibiting extra data structures. The point of uploading the code was to show that the algorithm was sound. You can always implement QuickSort etc. yourself. I think that the approach here is correct, it didn't include details for an in-place solution, but that wasn't a requirement when I answered this question.

Comment: @Andreas The second example input output pair, was not present when I answered this question.

Comment: @Nathan "Prohibit sorting" is from "respective order" combined with example of input `1 -4 -7 6 -5 2` gives output `1 -4 6 -7 2 -5`, showing that order of positive values remain `1 6 2` and order of negative values remain `-4 -7 -5`, aka *not sorted numerically*. Any solution that sorts the data is invalid.

Comment: @Nathan Second example was there when I left my first comment, pointing out that sorting was incorrect. 30 minutes later, you both commented and updated answer, insisting on sorting the data.

Comment: @Andreas that is true, that is why in the comment I said it was my initial thought. This was referring to what I saw when I first answered this question. The subsequent edits were there to clarify that in response to the downvote.

Answer (score -2):

make two arrays and sort them.

```
for i=1;i<length(a)+1;i++
    if a[i]>=0
       positive.add(a[i])
    else
        negative.add(a[i])
positive=sort(positive)
negative=sort(negative)
end
j=0
for i=1;i<(length(a)+1)/2;i+=2 %I assume the input is even and has an equal number of positive and negative numbers
    j++
    out[i]=positive(j)
    out[i+1]=negative(j)
end
```

sort comes from import java.util.Arrays, but you can implement your own.

edit: seems like you don't need them sorted? then skip the sort command, the positive and negative arrays extracted as above should work in the second loop and provide your required output.

the solution without sortin would be O(N), so save for a few machine cycles it's the best you can get.

Comment: there's nothing in the question about sorting.

Comment: well if 3 answers got it wrong it may be kinda on you, what do you think? :P my pseudo should work if you remove the sort lines, hope you realize it.

Comment: Question is specific that values should **not** be sorted, e.g. positive numbers must maintain relative order. "respective order" doesn't mean "sorted", and second example clarifies this, e.g. positive values maintain relative order of `1 6 2`.

Comment: solution should be inplace. No extra space can be used!

Comment: @Andreas if you don't sort my positive and negative arrays the second loop ,as I wrote, it maintains their ''relative order'' (which is not their relative sorting order, I guess) and takes one from the positive and one from the negative. O(n) so it shoudn't exceed the time limit. Don't see the problem tbh.

Comment: No additional data structure can be used. @Andreas

Comment: @sahilmehta if it's in place then what about the rotate right method? doesn't it work simply switching the current out of place element with the next ''valid'' element? that method increases your complexity by quite a bit. I'll take a look at the rest of your code tho.

Comment: No, rotate right method is inplace as I am shifting all elements within the same array and using a variable for storing a value which will be lost in shifting.

Comment: @sahilmehta Ok now I got the problem, you infact need to rotate. what about storing the last known position for the next positive and negative entries? you don't need to search from the current position (j=i+1) but from their previous positions, don't you? this is huge in a scenario when the array to arrange is like -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 ....... -10000 1 2 3 4 ..... 10000

Comment: @user3149593 but we cannot use additional data structure